# Eclipse Android Development Code for adding Buttons in the running Application

Tags: android, eclipse, button, user-interface, customization

I want to build an application in which the User is able to add and to remove buttons, that send a certain command onClick. But I have no idea how to do this in the Code. I don't know much about programming in Android. I already programmed in Java, but I'm new in this area of development.

I'd be very thankful for some suggestions on how to manage this.

Answer (score 0):

Look into adding views programmatically with the LayoutInflater.